# How to attach an event handler from a customcontrol to a parent's viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a long chain of usercontrols, some of which have customcontrols. In a standard MVVM fashion, I have a button that binds to the viewmodel as:

```
  <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding InsertCharacter}" />
```

The viewmodel for this this button now raises an event as:

```
    private DelegateCommand insertCharacter;
    public ICommand InsertCharacter
    {
        get
        {
            if (insertCharacter == null)
            {
                insertCharacter = new DelegateCommand(
                    () =>
                    {
                        InsertCharacterEventArgs e = new InsertCharacterEventArgs
                        {
                            InsertPosition = 1,
                            LengthOfInsertion= 20,
                            CharacterToInsert = 'C'
                        };

                        OnInsertCharacter(e);
                    });
            }
            return insertCharacter;
        }
    }


    // Raise the InsertCharacter event.
    public void OnInsertCharacter(InsertCharacterEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<InsertCharacterEventArgs> handler = InsertCharacterEvent;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<InsertCharacterEventArgs> InsertCharacterEvent;
```

Now several layers down, I have a CustomControl that I wish to listen to the event. The customcontrol is instantiated by the xaml from its usercontrol. The resulting visual tree from the  customcontrol up is:

```
CustomInkCanvas        <-- My CustomControl
Grid
ScrollContentPresenter
Grid
ScrollViewer
Canvas
Grid
ContentPresenter
Border
InkEditorView              <--InkEditorView
```

So, when the button is placed on the InkEditorView.xaml, and the corresponding event is raised from the InkEditorViewModel.cs, how can I have the custom control, CustomInkCanvas, be listening for the event?

Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: How are the content items of the 'ContentPresenter' populated? In code or XAML? You probably should hook up the event when adding the InkEditorView.

Comment: what about `<Style TargetType="{x:Type InkEditorView}"><EventSetter Event="<yourEvent>" Handler="YourHandlerInCustomInkCanvas"/>`.HTH